# nothing is visible in router react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsx, mern

the following code is not showing any content on the web screen/page

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar.jsx";
import Tef from './components/Tef';
import About from './components/About';
import Home from './components/Home';

import {useState} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Routes as Switch , Route ,Link}from "react-router-dom";

function Main() {



    const [mode, setMode] = useState("Dark")
    const [NavbarIDUS , setNavbarID] = useState("Heading-Nav_D")
    const [divIDUS , setDivID] = useState("Nav-bg_D")
    const [PIDUS , setPID] = useState("title_D")
    const [CIDUS , setCID] = useState("contents_D")


    const lightTheme = () =>
        {
            setMode("Dark")
            setCID("contents_D")
            setDivID("Nav-bg_D")
            setNavbarID("heading-Nav_D")
            setPID("title_D")
            document.body.style.background = "#1E1E1E"
            document.body.style.color = "white"
        }
        const darkTheme = () =>
        {
            setMode("Light")
            setCID("contents")
            setDivID("Nav-bg")
            setNavbarID("heading-Nav")
            setPID("title")
            document.body.style.background = "#EEE"
            document.body.style.color = "black"
        }

    //mode handler
    const modeHandler = (event) =>
    {   
        if(mode === "Dark")
        {
            darkTheme();
        }

        else
        {
            lightTheme();
        }

    }

    //renderer
return(<>
<Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
</>    );


}
export default Main;
```

so WHAT can i do to make it work like it should

i was expecting to see some content on the screen but i give me a blank screen

i followed a website https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start
but it was not working for me so what should i do???

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? A guide written for version 5 won't work with version 6, and based on the fact you're importing `Routes` and renaming it to `Switch` i think you're using version 6.

Comment: i'm using version 6

Comment: Why are you using the tutorials for react-router v5 if you're using react-router v6? The tutorials for that are up on https://reactrouter.com/main/start/tutorial so this is kind of a problem of your own making: don't follow tutorials for different versions. The [semver](https://semver.org/) way of versioning, which react-router adheres to, means that different major versions as incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you are using version 6, but you have `<switch>` in your code. That is version 5 syntax. Here is a [React Router V6](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ky53b4?file=src/App.js) example.

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/About">About</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/Users">Users</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/Users" element={<Users />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Edit: [Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component" occurs for multiple reasons](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-body#:%7E:text=The%20error%20%22Invalid%20hook%20call,package%20in%20the%20same%20project.) If you are getting an invalid hook error then this is not related to the react router if you have followed the V6 examples correctly. There are a few things that can be causing that issue. [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Change

> import {useState} from 'react';

To
`import React, {useState} from 'react';`

Comment: no , it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? You have to give more data than that. Just saying "it didn't work" doesn't allow us to help. Are you using version 5 or version 6? You claim to be using version 6, but you have version 5 code and links. Check your package.json and that will tell you what version you are using. If you are using version 6 then you have to follow that logic and syntax.

Comment: on console log it says Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Comment: ^6.4.2 is the react router version

Comment: Check my edit. Chances are this error is not related to the react router. You can't use hooks outside of a react functional component. Without seeing more of your code it will be hard to tell what exactly is causing it so I included a couple of articles that might help you out.

Comment: it still dosen't work

Comment: What code do you need to see"Without seeing more of your code " ?